# How to reshape submatrix into another existing matrix without an intermediate matrix (using Eigen)

Tags: eigen

I'm fairly new to Eigen. I have a primary and secondary question.

The primary question is that I would like to copy a submatrix into another existing matrix and reshape it during the process without the need for a temparary matrix.

The secondary question is similar, can I generate a linSpaced Vector and copy it into an existing Matrix with the same dimensions of the vector without the need for a temporary Vector?

The following code shows solutions using temporary variables,

```
void main(void)
{
Eigen::Matrix<double,3,4> mOut;
mOut.setZero();

// generate linspaced data for mIn [SECONDARY QUESTION]
Eigen::Matrix<double,36,1> mIn;
Eigen::VectorXd tmpIn(Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(36,0,35));
mIn = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,36,1>>(tmpIn.data());


std::cout << "mIn = " << mIn << std::endl;

// copy a subset of mIn into mOut [PRIMARY QUESTION]
Eigen::Matrix<double,12,1> tmpOut(mIn.block<12,1>(24,0));
mOut = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,4>>(tmpOut.data(),3,4);

std::cout << "mOut = " << mOut << std::endl;
}
```

I tried the following for the primary question but it did not work,

```
mOut = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,4>>(mIn.block<12,1>(24,0));
```

if gave an error,

```
Error   5   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'Eigen::Block<XprType,BlockRows,BlockCols,InnerPanel>' to 'Eigen::Map<PlainObjectType,MapOptions>'
```

Comment: The following works for the "primary" question: 

`mOut = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,4>>(mIn.tail(12).data());` 

Still investigating a solution for the "secondary" question...

Comment: Alternative syntax: `mOut = Eigen::Matrix<double,3,4>::Map(mIn.tail<12>().data());`. There is a long-pending pull-request which adds `reshape` funtionality: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/pull-requests/41. And for the other question: What exactly is the problem with `mIn = Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(36,0,35);`? Both questions would be more interesting if `mIn` would not be a vector (i.e., having more than 1 column)

Comment: @chtz, thanks for the obvious solution for the "secondary". <sheepish grin>